# mysql #1064 error in Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

MySQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE ORD( ORDID NUMERIC( 4 ) NOT NULL , ORDERDATE DATE, COMMPLANCHAR( 1 ) , CUSTID NUMERIC( 6 ) NOT NULL , SHIPDATE DATE, TOTAL NUMERIC( 8, 2 ) CONSTRAINT TOTAL_ZERO CHECK (

TOTAL >=0
), CONSTRAINT ORD_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY ( CUSTID ) REFERENCES CUSTOMER( CUSTID ) , CONSTRAINT ORD_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY ( ORDID ) ) ;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CONSTRAINT TOTAL_ZERO CHECK (TOTAL >= 0), CONSTRAINT
>   ORD_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KE' at line 8

Comment: Are you sure is mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma and a space

```
CREATE TABLE ORD
( 
  ORDID NUMERIC( 4 ) NOT NULL, 
  ORDERDATE DATE, 
  COMMPLAN CHAR( 1 ), 
  CUSTID NUMERIC( 6 ) NOT NULL, 
  SHIPDATE DATE, 
  TOTAL NUMERIC( 8, 2 ),
  CONSTRAINT TOTAL_ZERO CHECK (TOTAL >= 0), 
  CONSTRAINT ORD_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY ( CUSTID ) REFERENCES CUSTOMER( CUSTID ), 
  CONSTRAINT ORD_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY ( ORDID ) 
);
```

And AFAIK MySQL ignores `check` contraints.

Comment: Also, it's not a valid table definition for MySQL, with a check constraint in it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: You can define a check constraint in MySQL. It is just not used by the engine.

Comment: Yep, my bad.  I knew it wouldn't work, so I had never actually tried it.